# Spring JMS: each DefaultMessageListenerContainer deployment takes longer than one before

Tags: spring, jms, jetty, activemq-classic, spring-jms

We're using Active MQ 5.6.0, and have configured a number of JMS message listeners (17 currently), each using a Spring 3.1.1 DefaultMessageListenerContainer, deploying to a Jetty 7.

First of all, message routing and handling works and performs fine. The problem is the time it takes to **deploy** the Spring configuration: each deployment takes longer than the one before it, so we're talking something like polynomial rather than linear time. That's going to be crippling if we ever get to 30 or so.

The example (trimmed) log file shows the 17 deployments appearing to fight one another for connection, until - after over 2.5 minutes - all are connected:

```
22:33:21,147 - (Def...r) - JMS message listener invoker needs to establish shared Connection
22:33:22,148 - (Def...r) - JMS message listener invoker needs to establish shared Connection
22:33:23,160 - (Def...r) - JMS message listener invoker needs to establish shared Connection
22:33:23,166 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerA' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:33:24,160 - (Def...r) - JMS message listener invoker needs to establish shared Connection
22:33:24,172 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerB' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:33:25,173 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerC' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:33:26,184 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerD' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:33:27,166 - (Def...r) - JMS message listener invoker needs to establish shared Connection
[*snip*]
22:35:25,135 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerI' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:35:26,146 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerH' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:35:27,167 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerD' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:35:28,178 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerE' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:35:29,179 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerF' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:35:31,191 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerG' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:35:32,192 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerH' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:35:33,203 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerI' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:35:34,214 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerJ' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:35:35,225 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerK' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:35:36,229 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerL' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:35:37,230 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerM' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:35:38,242 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerN' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:35:40,266 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerC' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:35:41,277 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerB' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:35:42,280 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerA' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:35:44,292 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerN' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:35:45,293 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerM' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:35:46,294 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerL' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:35:47,300 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerK' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:35:48,282 - (Def...r) - JMS message listener invoker needs to establish shared Connection
22:35:48,311 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerJ' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:35:49,322 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerI' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:35:50,322 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerH' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:35:51,323 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerG' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:35:53,345 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerF' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:35:54,366 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerE' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:35:55,367 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerD' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:35:56,378 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerH' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:35:57,389 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerI' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:35:58,394 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerJ' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:35:59,400 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerK' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:00,396 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerL' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:01,409 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerM' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:02,412 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerN' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:03,421 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerO' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:04,422 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerA' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:05,426 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerB' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:06,437 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerC' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:09,471 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerO' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:10,472 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerN' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:11,483 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerM' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:12,483 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerL' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:13,459 - (Def...r) - JMS message listener invoker needs to establish shared Connection
22:36:13,494 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerK' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:14,515 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerJ' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:15,516 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerI' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:16,518 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerH' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:17,530 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerD' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:18,541 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerE' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:19,542 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerF' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:21,546 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerG' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:22,557 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerH' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:23,569 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerI' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:24,580 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerJ' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:25,581 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerK' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:26,582 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerL' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:27,593 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerM' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:28,594 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerN' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:29,605 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerO' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:30,616 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerP' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:32,638 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerC' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:33,639 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerB' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:34,650 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerA' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:36,674 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerP' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:37,685 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerO' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:38,805 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerN' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:39,806 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerM' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:40,653 - (Def...r) - JMS message listener invoker needs to establish shared Connection
22:36:40,807 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerL' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:41,824 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerK' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:42,825 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerJ' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:43,837 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerI' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:44,838 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerH' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:45,851 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerG' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:47,863 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerF' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:48,874 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerE' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:49,875 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerD' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:50,876 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerH' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:51,891 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerI' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:52,902 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerJ' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:53,913 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerK' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:54,924 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerL' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:55,925 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerM' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:56,926 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerN' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:57,937 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerO' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:58,935 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerP' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:36:59,936 - (Def...r) - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://HandlerQ' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
22:37:00,520 - (Def...r) - Successfully refreshed JMS Connection
22:37:00,520 - (Def...r) - Successfully refreshed JMS Connection
22:37:00,520 - (Def...r) - Successfully refreshed JMS Connection
22:37:00,520 - (Def...r) - Successfully refreshed JMS Connection
22:37:00,520 - (Def...r) - Successfully refreshed JMS Connection
22:37:00,520 - (Def...r) - Successfully refreshed JMS Connection
22:37:00,520 - (Def...r) - Successfully refreshed JMS Connection
22:37:00,520 - (Def...r) - Successfully refreshed JMS Connection
22:37:00,520 - (Def...r) - Successfully refreshed JMS Connection
22:37:00,520 - (Def...r) - Successfully refreshed JMS Connection
22:37:00,520 - (Def...r) - Successfully refreshed JMS Connection
22:37:00,520 - (Def...r) - Successfully refreshed JMS Connection
```

For the sake of brevity, I won't post each Spring bean, but here are the important bits:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="srcConnectionFactory" jndi-name="${jndi.jms.connfactory}">
    <jee:environment>
        java.naming.factory.initial = ${jndi.jms.naming.factory.initial}
        java.naming.provider.url = ${jndi.jms.naming.url}
    </jee:environment>
</jee:jndi-lookup>

<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="srcConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="cacheConsumers" value="false"/>
    <property name="reconnectOnException" value="true"/>
    <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="20"></property>
</bean>

<jee:jndi-lookup id="handlerA_Dest" jndi-name="handlerA">
    <jee:environment>
        java.naming.factory.initial = ${jndi.jms.naming.factory.initial}
        java.naming.provider.url = ${jndi.jms.naming.url}
        queue.handlerA = handlerA
    </jee:environment>
</jee:jndi-lookup>

    [x 17]

<bean id="handlerA_Container" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer"
    p:connectionFactory-ref="connectionFactory"
    p:messageListener-ref="handlerA"
    p:destination-ref="handlerA_Dest">
    <property name="concurrentConsumers"><value>10</value></property>
    <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers"><value>10</value></property>
    <property name="idleConsumerLimit"><value>5</value></property>
</bean>     

    [x 17]
```

Any idea why these containers should be contending at all?

Unfortunately, the `MessageSelector` approach is not (any longer) an option for us. It's one Listener per type-of-Message.

---

**Update** It's true that, strictly speaking, the MQ broker is indeed down at the start of this deployment, but it's deployed into the same Jetty (this all happens in the Maven integration test phase), so even if there was a brief period where the broker started up second, I wouldn't expect it to be 2-3 minutes late.

What I'm seeing looks really looks like the broker deployment is being 'blocked' by this Spring deployment...

Comment: +1. Interesting problem. Have you been able to resolve this ?

Comment: I solved it by switching to the non-caching ConnectionFactory - that did the job.

Comment: Is that the solution or the workaround? Do you need the CachingFactory back?

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing to do with Spring or contention between clients.

The broker wasn't available from `22:33:23,166` until `22:37:00,520`.

```
Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Looks to me like they all connected within 1 millisecond as soon as the broker was available.

Comment: Yes, I think that's literally true, but our broker is deployed (via separate WAR) to our Jetty at the same time as the app with the Spring context, so even if there was a brief period (a matter of seconds?) where the broker started up second, I wouldn't expect it to be 2-3 minutes late. What I'm seeing looks really looks like the broker deployment is being blocked by the Spring deployment...

Comment: That sounds like a Jetty issue; all Spring is doing is waiting for the broker to start.

Comment: I'll see if I can jiggle the deploy order to get the broker up first. Not 100% convinced, though: how does this explain the fact that adding a new listener seems to add another 20-30 secs to the deploy time, unless the broker webapp start was being blocked somehow? This should all be constant time, not polynomial, not even linear IMHO.

Comment: I'm still not convinced there is a Spring issue. It is true that the initial connection establishment occurs on the container initialization thread. But, if the connection fails fast (which it should, with a 'connection refused' condition, it will immediatley had over the connection task to the listener thread. If you turn on DEBUG logging, you will see...

Comment: "18:33:09.427 DEBUG [main][org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer] Could not establish shared JMS Connection - leaving it up to asynchronous invokers to establish a Connection as soon as possible
javax.jms.JMSException: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://localhost:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused". So, it fails fast for me, regardless of how many containers I have. The context initialization completes and the retries run on separate threads. I suggest you turn on DEBUG logging to see where the time is being spent.

Comment: If I log the time difference between each of the 17 "Successfully started bean '<container>'", I get: 1 1 1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 secs. In between, I get a "Starting bean '<nextContainer>' ..." followed by a "Could not refresh JMS Connection" for each of the **previously started containers**, with 1 sec between each, hence each container start taking longer than the first.  Has a misconfiguration of mine caused this seemingly pointless refreshing? Without that, problem solved!

Comment: Pointing our DMLCs at the raw ConnectionFactory rather than the  Caching one seems to prevent the refreshing, and saves 182 of those 198 secs. Will need the cacheing back, though...

Comment: Interesting; does DEBUG logging shed any light? (My tests were with the CCF and I didn't see any delays, the connections failed fast and the retries were handed over to the consumer thread).

Comment: Sorry - I didn't see your previous comment. I wonder if the delay is your JNDI lookups? I just started 11 containers in 200ms (when the broker was down). Maybe if you run with DEBUG logging, you'll be able to see where the delay is?

Comment: Hoy you enabled DEBUG?   I have a similar problem.